# Prepositions: what relationships do 'to' and 'of' express?

Tags: prepositions

Preposition: What is the difference between to and of when expressing relation. Example: solution to the problem ; lid of the box

Comment: I believe a simple Google search on "to vs of" could get you the answers you are looking for.

Comment: The 'solution' is distinct from the 'problem' therefore the preposition is a matter of donation between the two, and a dative situation. The 'lid' is a part of the 'box' so the preposition is a matter of possessiveness, and therefore a genitive situation.

Comment: I see very little functional difference.

Comment: @aparente001 I do. I wouldn't use 'lid to the box' if it wasn't detachable and detached.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Oh.  Wow.  This reminds me of something a painter friend tried to explain to me once about the way he saw colors.  If you put a blue bowl on a tablecloth that has a yellow flower, the yellow changes the part of the blue bowl it's close to.  I probably didn't explain that as well as he did.  My point is that I couldn't see the difference between the plain blue and the yellow-influenced blue -- but he convinced me that he could.  More power to you (and the painter).  I suppose there are fine distinctions I can hear in music that some people can't.... Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

*X to Y* means X is moving in the direction of Y, or being pointed in the direction of Y - either in the physical sense of motion/heading or in a logical sense of progressing towards a goal/result/place.  It can also be short for *X is to Y* and functions as an infinitive marker.

*X of Y* means X is derived from Y or is dependent for existence on Y somehow - in a physical "possessive" sense, in a "Y is the purpose/source of X" sense, or in a "Y is a larger group/class from which we can take X" sense.

Very little is consistent in English, so of course there are exceptions to the above.

Answer (score 0):

These words have many uses, so a comprehensive answer must be to look at the dictionary.  Macmillan Dictionary has some good definitions with examples here:  [to](https://www.Macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/to_1) and [of](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/of_1).

With that caveat, here's an attempt at something of a more concise difference.  First of all, *to* and *from* are antonyms, of course. Also *to* is used to form the infinitive.

What I think you're having difficulty with is the difference when either is used to denote something like a compositional relationship between two objects or concepts.  Let's say that *of* denotes a tight, connected, compositional dependency.  *To* denotes a looser, disconnected, adjunct dependency (though still indicating some level of importance).

Compare the [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introduction+of+the+book%2Cintroduction+to+the+book%2Ctitle+of+the+book%2Ctitle+to+the+book%2Cpreface+to+the+book%2Cpreface+of+the+book%2C+author+of+the+book%2C+author+to+the+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20to%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctitle%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctitle%20to%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreface%20to%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreface%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20to%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0) for the following phrases (preferred usage in bold):

- **title of the book**, title to the book
- **author of the book**, author to the book
- preface of the book, **preface to the book**
- introduction of the book, **introduction to the book**

[image]

The title and the author are integral aspects of a book.  On the other hand, the introduction and the preface are considered to be more loosely related to the book.

In some cases, either word may be used with some slight grammatical changes.  *Of* may also denote "belonging to" or "ownership". *To* may also denote a more active role.

- She is a good friend of my mother's.  (Belonging.  She is one of my mother's friends.)
- She is a good friend to my mother.  (Active Role. She has done friendly things for my mother.)

In some situations, one or the other word absolutely must be used, while in other situations, one or the other is highly preferred, but a mistake could be considered somewhat forgivable.

- The history of Russia is ... GOOD
- The history to Russia is ... BAD
- The title of the book is "Don Quixote". GOOD
- The title to the book is "Don Quixote". POOR
- The name of the author is ... GOOD
- The name to the author is ... BAD

So the *solution of the problem* is poor, but understandable.  The *solution to the problem* is correct as it indicates the solution has an important relationship to the problem, but is not an integral part of the problem itself.  Compare with *the wording of the problem* or *aspects of the problem*.

*The lid of the box* is the lid that is currently connected to the box.  It's considered part of the box.  On the other hand, *the lid to the box* is not currently connected to the box.  When getting fountain drinks, one would speak of *the lids to the cups* but one might speak of *the lid of the cup* if you're talking about one particular cup that has a lid on it.